# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http while running the jenkins job from terminal

Tags: jenkins, curl

I tried to run the Jenkins job using "CURL" command but getting the below error

```
C:\Users\gd\Downloads\curl-7.66.0_2-win64-mingw\curl-7.66.0-win64-mingw\bin>

curl -X POST http://slack:11cf86296e48e9c5c3a8570aa1ccfc57a8@10.204.211.118:8080/job/test-job/build
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http

curl -X POST http://slack:11cf86296e48e9c5c3a8570aa1ccfc57a8@10.204.211.118:8080/job/test-job/build
```

when we hit that command from the command prompt, immediately Jenkins job should run in the Jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgEVj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For `could not resolve POST`: make sure to use `-X`, not `-x`

```
curl -X POST ...
```

You seem to have an extra http:// in the middle of your URL:

```
http://slack:11cf86296e48e9c5c3a8570aa1ccfc57a8@http:///:8080/job/test-slack/build
                                                ^^^^^^^
 Try instead to use "<ipaddress>" (to be replace by the actual Jenkins IP address)

http://slack:11cf86296e48e9c5c3a8570aa1ccfc57a8@<ipaddress>:8080/job/test-slack/build
```

Using a fully qualified named instead of an IP address would be preferable, but both should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the below to trigger the pipeline:-

```
curl -X POST slack:11cf86296e48e9c5c3a8570aa1ccfc57a8@<Jenkinshost>:8080/job/test-slack/build

curl -X POST http://slack:11cf86296e48e9c5c3a8570aa1ccfc57a8@<Jenkinshost>:8080/job/test-slack/build
```

Comment: I have tried the above commands but still, the issue is there. Please check the below output from the command line

Comment: You are using "x" whereas you have to use "X" for the POST method